# scan txt file with keep the white space between character

Tags: r

I'm currently learning Sentiment Analysis in r , 


i got stuck in part how to properly read and import the data into my case,


i want to know how to read data using scan() in r ,

but how to make that it gonna read the white space too between string in one row from the txt

case :

for example, 


 **positive.txt** contain :

```
Not Strong
```

*the string above written inside txt file without separated semi colon or comma, just line spacing \n

---

so, i read that txt formatted file by using this in r :

> positive -> scan('positive.txt', what = ' ', sep="\n")

there's no error,  

but after i check, 
 
the main problem is read the imported file by using scan() will read the white space between character, 

so from input **positive.txt** file: 


1) **Not Strong**

the result using scan() into **positive.txt** file in r will end up like this :

1) **Not**

2) **Strong**

What i expected is : 
how to make scan() file in r keep maintain the white space from character inside **positive.txt**  :

1) **Not Strong**

the result i expected is still :

1) **Not Strong**

*note, the number 1 is only some guide like some kind index, to help understand this problems.

Comment: I think you want `readLines` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat /tmp/file.txt
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
```

in R:

```
file.contents <- readLines('/tmp/file.txt')

file.contents

# [1] "this is line 1" "this is line 2" "this is line 3"
```

Good luck with Sentiment Analysis, it's a great topic!